# Json Parsing html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this json and i want parse it.

I use this code but it doesn't work...
where is my error?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parsing</title>

</head>
<body>
    <script>

       $.getJSON('http://ciao.php', { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
         $('body').append($('<p>').html('Nr : '+ Nr));
    });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console say?

Comment: What does the browser's developer tools Net tab say? Is the HTTP request and response what you are expecting?

Comment: What happens if you add some console.log statements inside the callback function? Does the function run at all? Does `data` contain the data you expect? When you loop over `data` are `index` and `element` the values you expect?

Comment: Didn't you notice the syntax error that would have been reported in the JS console and is made obvious by Stackoverflow's syntax highlighting?

Comment: `+ Nr SAT` is surely wrong

Comment: This is the report of the console :XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sath3g.altervista.org/index.php?get_param=value. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You should consider using JSONP then, because you're targeting another domain. You can read up more on it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: In wich way?How i have to use jsonp?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

```
$('body').append($('<p>').html('Nr SAT: '+ Nr SAT));
```

`Nr SAT` is not a JavaScript variable. You can access the JSON from the request like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://sath3g.altervista.org/index.php', { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) { 
     $('body').append($('<p>').html('Nr SAT: '+ data["Nr SAT"]));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with CornéM, but you write :

```
<head>
    <title>Parsing</title>

</head>
```

did you implement jQuery in your real script ? else it must be a part of the problem ;)

Comment: I don't understand.....Can you explain me the problem in a way more easy?....thanks

Comment: of course, do you add the tag 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="<path to Jquery.js>"></script>` in `<head>`  ?

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parsing</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ja.js"><script>
</head>
 <script>
  $.getJSON('http://sath3g.altervista.org/index.php', { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) { 
   $('body').append($('<p>').html('Nr SAT: '+ data["Nr SAT"]));
  });
 </script>
 
 <body >
  <p>ciao<p>
 </body> 
</html>   I fix the code. It doesn't work but in the console i haven't some error. What i have to do??

Comment: after corrections, your script is :
`<script>
  $(function(){
   $.getJSON('http://sath3g.altervista.org/index.php', {get_param: 'value' }, function(data) {
      $('body').append($('<p>').html('Nr SAT: '+ data["Nr SAT"]));
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
  </script>`

but your real problem is the site you want to get a response, it says : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sath3g.altervista.org/index.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: so if it's your page you need to allow access from other websites, else use an other method to get this JSON like PHP